# Used Air Drop to move a folder with mp3 files in it to my phone. Where are they now?

Tags: macos, ios, music.app, airdrop

I moved some mp3s to my iPhone using AirDrop expecting they would be available in the Music app, but I can't seem to find them. Where can I find them on my phone?

There was no error or anything saying the files didn't go through. It appears as if they have been copied to my phone.

Comment: AFAIK the only way to get music files in to the Music app is via direct sync with an iTunes instance running on a PC or Mac or via iCloud Music Match. There is no import via AirDrop capabilities.

Comment: It is kind of amazing that iOS lets you move these files, but doesn't give any way to access them. Why not either say "You can't move this type of file using Air Drop" or let you access them?

Answer (score 3):

You can add a 3rd party app that supports mp3 playback to the iOS device and if they support AirDrop you will get a prompt after AirDrop of mp3 from computer to iOS device asking which program to open the mp3.  My prompts include iMovie, Evernote and Google Drive.  I use Evernote.  This does not put it in iOS iTunes.  But I'm not always near the computer that hosts my main iTunes and I use Evernote for the immediate need and then add to iTunes from Evernote on the iTunes main host when the opportunity arises.

Answer (score 0):

the music file went to the iMovie app, don't know why but from iMac to iPad or to iPod touch? in iMovies is where its ends. in the meantime apple decide to fix this the only thing you can do is add the incoming music file as a new project in iMovie :))) yup funny..or just connect the iPad or iPod touch to the mac computer an transfer through iTunes.